# whitespace in the right side of my webpage

Tags: html, css

There is a strange space on the right side of my web, whenever i zoom in. the space becomes bigger. can someone help me how to get rid of that.

here is my html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>thesis</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "styles and pics/index.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id = "outer_wrapper">
    <header>
        <section>
            <input type = "text" id = "username" name = "username" class = "text" placeholder = "E-mail"/>
            <input type = "password" id = "password" name = "password" class = "text" placeholder = "Password"/>
            <input type = "submit" id = "submit_login" name = "submit_login" class = "submit" value = "login"/>
        </section>
    </header>
    <footer>
        footer
    </footer>
</div>  
</body>
```

here is my css:

```
*{ padding:0px; margin:0px; }
body{ text-align:center;}
#outer_wrapper{ width:100%; height:700px; background-color:yellow; position:relative;}
header{ background-color:blue;height:70px;display:block;position:absolute;top:0px;width:100%;}
header section{ position:relative;top:20px;left:120px;}
.text{ height:25px;width:200px;padding-left:5px;}
#submit_login{height:25px;width:70px;background-color:green;border:0px;outline:none;cursor:pointer;color:white;}
.text,#submit_login{ margin-left:10px;}
footer{background-color:blue;height:40px;position:absolute;bottom:0px;width:100%;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`section { left: 120px; }` is causing the issue. By default, section is inheriting `width: 100%` so moving it left is adding 120px to the total width.

Assuming you intend the header section to be offset 120px to the left, there are at least two ways to fix the issue:

1. Change `section { left: 120px; }` to `section { margin-left: 120px; }`
   or
2. Add `overflow: hidden;` to header element i.e. `header { overflow: hidden; }`

Otherwise just remove `left: 120px;`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the left:120px from: "header section{ position:relative;top:20px;left:120px;}"
Should be "{position:relative;top:20px;}".

Comment: but how would i position my header section?